# Select all column in QueryExpression CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have this QueryExpression in my code.

```
 QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression() { };

 query.EntityName = "country";
 query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "2digitiso", "3digitiso");

 EntityCollection retrieved = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

My question is, Is there a way to select all the columns in the "country" without providing any ColumnSet? pretty much I want something like the `SELECT *` from the SQL Query.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, if you change your third line to look like this

```
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
```

then it will select all columns

Comment: You get the same effect if you don't specify any Column Set

Answer (score 6):

Use this it works in CRM 2015

```
query.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;
```

and do not set anything in

```
query.ColumnSet
```

Answer (score 2):

yes that's right
if you want retrieve all all columns means we have to specify the property "true" otherwise we have to customize the column set like `ColumnSet ss=new ColumnSet("name","address","gender");`